# Checkcolumn listeners not working in Extjs

Tags: extjs

How to declare the listeners for checkcolumn in editor grid panel in order to get the checked checkbox value in extjs?

Answer (score 0):

A simple example..

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields : ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'active'],
data   : {
    items : [
        { name : 'Lisa',  email : 'lisa@simpsons.com',  phone : '555-111-1224', active : true  },
        { name : 'Bart',  email : 'bart@simpsons.com',  phone : '555-222-1234', active : true  },
        { name : 'Homer', email : 'homer@simpsons.com',  phone : '555-222-1244', active : false },
        { name : 'Marge', email : 'marge@simpsons.com', phone : '555-222-1254', active : true  }
    ]
},
proxy  : {
    type   : 'memory',
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'items'
    }
}
  });

 Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title    : 'Simpsons',
height   : 200,
width    : 400,
renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
store    : store,
columns  : [
    { xtype : 'checkcolumn', text : 'Active', dataIndex : 'active' },
    { text : 'Name', dataIndex : 'name' },
    { text : 'Email', dataIndex : 'email', flex : 1 },
    { text : 'Phone', dataIndex : 'phone' }

]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**checkchange** event give the information of the check column.This event Fires when the checked state of a row changes

```
    {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'active',
        listeners : {
            'checkchange' : function(this,rowindex,isChecked){
                 console.log(rowindex);//this return the index of the record check in gridusing this index you can get the record from the store that is used by the Grid panel.
        } 
        }
```

Hope this help you to get the Required Information.Best of Luck!!
Refer to link for more Information 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Check-event-checkchange

Comment: does this method apply as well as in Extjs3.4 ?